# Getting BulkwriteError when using MongoDb with djangorestframework-simplejwt?

Tags: django, mongodb, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am using MongoDB and SimpleJWT in DjangoREST to authenticate and authorize users. I tried to implement user logout, whereby in SimpleJWT it's basically blacklisting a user token. When the first user logs in, everything seems okay and their `refresh token` is added to the `Outstanding token` table. But when I try to log in a second user, I get the below error:

```bash
 raise BulkWriteError(full_result)
pymongo.errors.BulkWriteError: batch op errors occurred, full error: {'writeErrors': [{'index': 0, 'code': 11000, 'keyPattern': {'jti_hex': 1}, 'keyValue': {'jti_hex': None}, 'errmsg': 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: fsm_database.token_blacklist_outstandingtoken index: token_blacklist_outstandingtoken_jti_hex_d9bdf6f7_uniq dup key: { jti_hex: null 
}', 'op': {'id': 19, 'user_id': 7, 'jti': '43bccc686fc648f5b60b22df3676b434', 'token': 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImV4cCI6MTY1OTY1NDUzNCwiaWF0IjoxNjU5NTY4MTM0LCJqdGkiOiI0M2JjY2M2ODZmYzY0OGY1YjYwYjIyZGYzNjc2YjQzNCIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjd9.aQmt5xAyncfpv_kDD2pF7iS98Hld98LhG6ng-rCW23M', 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 
8, 3, 23, 8, 54, 125539), 'expires_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 4, 23, 8, 54), '_id': ObjectId('62eb00064621b38109bbae16')}}], 'writeConcernErrors': [], 'nInserted': 0, 'nUpserted': 0, 'nMatched': 0, 'nModified': 0, 'nRemoved': 0, 'upserted': []}

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MR.Robot\.virtualenvs\fsm-GjGxZg3c\lib\site-packages\djongo\cursor.py", line 51, in execute
    self.result = Query(
  File "C:\Users\MR.Robot\.virtualenvs\fsm-GjGxZg3c\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 784, in __init__
    self._query = self.parse()
  File "C:\Users\MR.Robot\.virtualenvs\fsm-GjGxZg3c\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 869, in parse
    raise exe from e
djongo.exceptions.SQLDecodeError:

        Keyword: None
        Sub SQL: None
        FAILED SQL: INSERT INTO "token_blacklist_outstandingtoken" ("user_id", "jti", "token", "created_at", "expires_at") VALUES (%(0)s, %(1)s, %(2)s, %(3)s, %(4)s)
        Params: [7, '43bccc686fc648f5b60b22df3676b434', 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImV4cCI6MTY1OTY1NDUzNCwiaWF0IjoxNjU5NTY4MTM0LCJqdGkiOiI0M2JjY2M2ODZmYzY0OGY1YjYwYjIyZGYzNjc2YjQzNCIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjd9.aQmt5xAyncfpv_kDD2pF7iS98Hld98LhG6ng-rCW23M', datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 3, 23, 8, 54, 125539), datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 4, 23, 8, 54)]
        Version: 1.3.6
```

MongoDB seems to have a problem inserting the token for the second user in the outstanding table.
How can I fix this?

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the djangorestframework too. Do you managed to fix it?

Comment: No, I switched to PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I asked the library maintainers and they said that they don't support MongoDB. Check out this [issue](https://github.com/jazzband/djangorestframework-simplejwt/issues/598).